# python interpreter from spyder works but python from console has no modules found

Tags: python, pip, python-3.8

I need to run Python 3.8 for my ROS2 installation on Ubuntu 22.04.

When I open Spyder it defaults to Python 3.10.6 and all the scripts work, however when I run Python from the console it uses Python 3.8.15 and no modules are found.

How do I ensure that all pip installations can be seen by Python 3.8?

```
update-alternatives --config python is set to version 3.8
  * 0            /usr/bin/python3.8    3         auto mode
```

```
$PATH variable outputs: /home/ros2/ros2_dashing/install/cyclonedds/bin:/home/ros2/ros2_dashing/install/ament_flake8/bin:/home/ros2/ros2_dashing/install/ament_cppcheck/bin:/opt/ros/humble/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/ros2/.local/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that works for me.

From the console, install each module specifically for the required python version:

`python3.8 -m pip install <module>`